# how to add watermark to the videos without lossing its quality and faster in flutter

Tags: flutter, ffmpegkit

i have used [ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^5.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter) to add watermark to the videos.
using below command :

```
"-i $videoPath -i $watermarkImagePath -filter_complex \"[1:v]scale=w=$scaledWatermarkWidth:h=$scaledWatermarkHeight[v1];[0:v][v1]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5[v]\" -map [v] -map 0:a $outputFilePath"
```

but its compressing the video and it generate the Mb video in Kb size so i have tried "libx264", "preset fast" etc. for quality and faster processing but its throwing errors like libx264 is unrecognized codec so how can i done this?.

Comment: how about just using overlay or stack ?

Comment: Regarding the `x264` lib, maybe it's not supported in flutter version of ffmpeg kit. You can ask in their Github repository. They say there are various packages (min, audio, full, etc.) but I don't see how to select one in flutter so it includes x264, maybe it's only for Android.